# SharePoint App - Pressing Refresh opens resend Information dialog

Tags: provider-hosted-app, internet-explorer

I'm doing a sharepoint provider hoster app. When I'm pressing refreh (F5 or in the browser) after the webapplication has loaded I'm getting a dialog for resending information. ("To display the webpage again, the browser needs to resend the information you've previously submitted").

I didnt submit any information. 
I've cleared the whole application and just loading an empy page. But there the dialog also appears.

Do you've got any idea?

I'm creating an app with angluarjs but I don't think thats the problem becauseI cleared the whole page.

Comment: Does this happen when you come out of Edit Page ? Try typing the specific pages URL, then refresh should not ask for resend.

Comment: Can you use Fiddler to see what POST requests is made?